# Laravel Auth::get() fails after redirecting to page

Tags: php, session, authentication, laravel

I'm following a tutorial on Laravel authentication to learn a bit more about it. I've got to a point where I cannot go any further because i'm confused.

Resume of the problem: I do a Auth::attempt, it works, but once i redirect to a page, Auth::get() doesn't work anymore.

this is my controller:

```
public function postSignIn()
{
    $validator = Validator::make(Input::all(),
        array(
            'usrUsername'   => 'required'
            ,'usrPassword'  => 'required'
        ));

    if($validator->fails()){
        return Redirect::route('account-sign-in-get')
            ->withErrors($validator)
            ->withInput();
    }else{

        $auth = Auth::attempt(array(
            'usrUsername' => Input::get('usrUsername')
            ,'password' => Input::get('usrPassword')
            ,'usrIsActive' => 1
        ));

        if($auth){
            return Redirect::intended('/')
                ->with('global', 'Signed in. Have a great adventure!');
        }else{
            return Redirect::route('account-sign-in-get')
                ->with('global', 'Are you sure that is your correct username/password combination?');
        }
    }

}
```

This is my html side on navigation.blade.php:

```
@if(Auth::check())
        <li><a href="{{ URL::route('account-logout') }}">Sign Out</a></li>
    @else
        <li><a href="{{ URL::route('account-create-get') }}">Create account</a></li>
        <li class="nav-divider"></li>
        <li><a href="{{ URL::route('account-sign-in-get') }}"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-off"></i> Sign In</a></li>
    @endif
```

When I get into my redirected view after logging in, I can see the global message, but Auth::get() is always false. What am I missing?

Edit: I placed an if condition with Auth::check() after the if($auth) and it goes into the TRUE value. So yeah, on the redirect it seems it loses all its Auth information?

Edit2: My user if necessary:

```
class User extends Eloquent implements UserInterface, RemindableInterface {

use UserTrait, RemindableTrait;

protected $fillable = array('usrEmail', 'usrUsername', 'usrPassword', 'usrCode', 'usrIsActive');

/**
 * The database table used by the model.
 *
 * @var string
 */
protected $table = 'users';

/**
 * The attributes excluded from the model's JSON form.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $hidden = array('usrPassword', 'usrCode');

// Tell eloquent the pasword field is "usrPassword"
public function getAuthPassword() {
    return $this->usrPassword;
}

}
```

Comment: I suppose you mean `Auth::check()`, not `Auth::get()` ?

Comment: Yes that is correct Kestutis. I will edit the text so its okay. Thank you for that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that the session is not persisting after you logged in using **Auth::attempt()**

In your **user class** (model), try to add

```
$primaryKey = ''; // add your user table primary key here
```

Then, your `postSignIn()` function, inside `if($auth) { ... }` , before the return, try to add

```
Auth::loginUsingId(Auth::user()->userTablePrimaryKey);
```

Comment: I will try that as soon as possible Raffy Cortez. Thank you so much for your insight.

Comment: why is this not metioned on the tutorial? (im using the default code on the scaffolding from composer)